# bitmap image file manipulation using bitmap file structure in c

Tags: c, file, bitmap, structure, bitmapimage

I want to implement a simple command line based image editor. The program will
provide a text based menu, which provides several functions for user to manipulate a windows
bitmap (.bmp) image file. The menu will include load image, rotate image, mirror image, save image
and quit options. The load image option will be used to open and read pixel values from a given
bitmap file. This option will also print out the basic properties, such as dimensions and total size, of the given file. The rotate and mirror options will manipulate previously read pixel values. An image
must be loaded before applying these options. The save option will save the pixel values in the
memory to a bitmap file with a given filename.

Which approach do you recommend for me about this project and about bitmap file structure?

It would be very appreciated if you give me advice even about one particular topic for example load the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[libbmp](http://code.google.com/p/libbmp/) will make your program all but trivial to implement.

Comment: thank you for your recommendation. I looked at the library but there is no function for reading bitmap files in it.

Comment: @hotaru, clearly there is.  That is the *entire purpose* of that library.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't find any and neither could these people http://code.google.com/p/libbmp/issues/detail?id=4
If you can find I'd be happy to see it cause I badly need it :D

Comment: @hotaru, what about all the `bmp_get_*` functions?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use C then try the libbmp library http://code.google.com/p/libbmp/

However, I'd recommend using C#, then the task would be trivial with the System.Drawing namespace.

Comment: thank you for your help unfortunately I have to use c for this project

Answer (score 0):

This function is used for loading a bmp file to memory.
you have to declare first a header file with bmp structure

```
BMP* load_BMP(char *filename);

BMP *bmp;       // local integer for file loaded
FILE *in;       // pointer for file opening
int rowsize;   

int row, col, color, i;
unsigned char b;

in=fopen(filename,"rb"); // open binary file
if (in==NULL)
{
    printf("Problem in opening file %s.\n",filename);
    return NULL;
}


bmp=(BMP*) malloc(sizeof(BMP)); //memory allocation
if (bmp==NULL)
{
    printf("Not enough memory to load the image.\n");
    return NULL;
}

fread(bmp->BM,2,1,in);
if (bmp->BM[0]!='B' || bmp->BM[1]!='M')
{
    printf("Bad BMP image file.\n");
    free(bmp);
    return NULL;
}

fread(&bmp->fileSize,4,1,in);
fread(&bmp->Reserved1,2,1,in);
fread(&bmp->Reserved2,2,1,in);
fread(&bmp->imageOffset,4,1,in);
fread(&bmp->imageHeaderSize,4,1,in);
fread(&bmp->imageWidth,4,1,in);

rowsize=4*((3*bmp->imageWidth+3)/4); //calculate rowsize because of padding

fread(&bmp->imageHeight,4,1,in);
fread(&bmp->colorPlanes,2,1,in);
fread(&bmp->compressionMethod,4,1,in);
fread(&bmp->imageSize,4,1,in);
fread(&bmp->hPPM,4,1,in);
fread(&bmp->vPPM,4,1,in);
fread(&bmp->paletteColors,4,1,in);
fread(&bmp->paletteImportantColors,4,1,in);


bmp->data=(unsigned char*) malloc(bmp->imageSize); //allocate memory for image data array
if (bmp->data==NULL)
{
    printf("There is not enough memory to load the image\n");
    free(bmp);
    return NULL;
}

for(row=0;row<bmp->imageHeight;row++)  //read picture data
{
    for(col=0;col<bmp->imageWidth;col++)
        for(color=0;color<=2;color++)
            fread(&bmp->data[row*rowsize+3*col+color],
            sizeof(unsigned char),1,in);

    //read extra bytes for end of row padding
    for(i=0;i<rowsize-3*bmp->imageWidth;i++)
        fread(&b,1,1,in);
}

fclose(in);
return bmp;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For C++, EasyBMP is on SourceForge:

> https://easybmp.sourceforge.net/

The coverage on SourceForge was expanded to include AVI as EasyBMPtoAVI:

> https://easybmptoavi.sourceforge.net/

A GitHub fork of EasyBMP that has an increasing level of C++ nativization is:

> https://github.com/aburgh/EasyBMP

I might put up GitHub clones of the entire histories of the SourceForge sources (since I have clones already locally staged). If so, then it will be listed in a later edit and/or comment.

The libbmp library

> https://code.google.com/archive/p/libbmp/

which is under GPL3 *is* EasyBMP - only rewritten in C and library-ified ... and also posted without acknowledgement to EasyBMP, which is under BSD license, not GPL. Also, libbmp doesn't have the "extensions" or "projects" source files in EasyBMP, nor anything from EasyBMPtoAVI. The "projects" files in EasyBMP are under GPL2.

EasyBMP is drop-in code, not a library, basically just two files: the *.cpp source and the *.h header. There are actually several headers, but they all come off the main *.h header and can easily be in-line substituted into it, since they're all small; so you're really just talking about two files. I think the reason for the layout, splitting the headers, was that originally, everything was in *.h files until version 1.01. There were actually 12-14 *.h files before a round of consolidation at version 0.55. The latest version of EasyBMP is 1.06 from December 2006, so there wasn't much further evolution after the changeover at 1.01.

You can treat libbmp as effectively a C translation of a subset of EasyBMP. If you're still in C, and not C++ (the original thread is 11 years ago, now), then it's easy enough to convert the C++ code - the full set of code - to C, using the code in libbmp as a guide.